# Getting Rid of White Flash in Windows 8 High Contrast Mode

Tags: windows-8, firefox, colors, accessibility, contrast

I am trying out Windows 8 and I see white flashes whenever I open a tab (and immediately switch) in Firefox. In Windows 7, I was able to get rid of this by setting the `Application Background` color to black. The registry value that corresponds to this color is the same for both OS, but the behaviors are different.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors]
"Window"="0 0 0"
```

The Firefox I am running is version 20.0, but this behavior was also tested in 19.0
Google Chrome always had white flashes.

Comment: I've never seen this behaviour in Firefox, Chrome, or any other browser on Windows 7 or Windows 8. Are you running up-to-date graphics drivers? Is your CPU powerful enough?

Comment: @Dai. This behavior happens for a split of second right before the page loads. I am running 3rd gen Intel Processor. I think its CPU and integrated GPU do not have any issues and they are loaded with the latest drivers.

Comment: Did my answer end up working for you?

Comment: @blackwind Unfortunately not, I gave up on using contract mode for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Tools > Options > Content > Colors. Even if you have "Use system colors" checked, Firefox still (for whatever reason) defaults in-progress tabs to the colors specified in this dialog. Change the "Background" color setting to black and restart Firefox to achieve your desired behavior.